# Check if current time is passed AM/PM in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, time

Here's the given time:

```
11:20 AM
or 01:00 PM
```

I need to check if current time is passed or not, using Javascript(without library)

Here's how I did it in java:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
    String currentTime = sdf.format(new Date());
    currentTime = timeConverter(currentTime,24);

    Date date = new Date() ;
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", 
    Locale.ENGLISH) ;
    dateFormat.format(date);

    if(dateFormat.parse(currentTime).after(dateFormat.parse(startTime24)))
                isClassComplete.setImageDrawable(progressIcon);
```

Help me to do it in Javascript.

Comment: I think there is no equivalent to SimpleDateFormat in Javascript, but there are libraries like https://momentjs.com/ which implement this function where you could look for a solution.

Also a regex would work and then compare to new Date().getMinutes() /.getHours().

Comment: So your question really is how to compare times in hh:mm am/pm format. That does not require a Date object, just simple parsing of the string. What have you tried in javascript/ECMAScript?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = new Date('1/10/2018 19:30')
var b = new Date('1/10/2018 20:00')
var difference = Math.floor((b - a) / 1000 / 60);
console.log(difference + ' minutes difference.');
```

The difference is time in seconds.

Comment: Using the built-in parser for non–standard strings (i.e. not one of the formats supported by ECMA-262) is strongly discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Where you just have a time string with no date, you can convert the time to a common denominator, say minutes, then compare that. E.g.

```js
/* Convert time string to minutes
 * @param {string} time: format hh:mm am/pm
 * @returns {number} time converted to minutes
*/
function timeToMins(time) {
  var b = time.split(/[:\s]/);
  return b[0]%12*60 + +b[1] + (/pm\s*$/i.test(time)? 720 : 0);
}

// E.g.
[['10 : 23pm','10:23am'],   // Tolerant of differing whitespace 
 ['12:12 am','12:12   pm'],
 ['12:12 pm','12:12 am   ']
].forEach(times => console.log(
    `${times[0]} < ${times[1]}? ${timeToMins(times[0]) < timeToMins(times[1])}`
  )
);
```

While the above is somewhat tolerant of differing whitespace, you should add validation to the string to confirm the format before processing and return a sensible message if it's not the required format. You may also want to extend it to support optional seconds and fractions of seconds.